# how to use Clustered and Nonclustered Indexes

Tags: sql-server

I have questions, 
there is a table with clustered indexes of eight columns if I do not use all its elements in the WHERE conditionals is this still valid?
There is also a table with four columns of indexes not grouped in a WHERE query. Are all indexes valid if used or only the first index predominates?

between clustered or Nonclustered indexes, which is more optimal if I have a query with conditions of four columns type OR.

Comment: This is likely better suited for [DBA](http://DBA.stackexchange.com) but a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on 8 columns sounds like a large design flaw.

Comment: I recommend benchmarking with two different indexes :)

Comment: This question is entirely too vague to provide a solid answer. I agree with @Larnu that a clustered index 8 columns wide sounds like the design went the wrong direction in a big way.

Comment: Clustered index is used to order data in a physical order, however it keeps all the data in leaf level node.
Nonclustered indexes we used to satisfy query to avoid performing scanning primary key which is clustered index. Basically non-clustered index can have key columns and include columns where key column will be your columns which used in where condition of a query and include columns used to avoid lookup using primary key clustered column (this will be your columns used in select). 
In your case will recommend you to use non-clustered index.